# Drupal 7, Entity Reference - display fields from referenced entity

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Entity Reference to link two content types: "Job Postings" and "Jobs".

"Job Postings" have an Entity Reference field called "Job Title", which references the "Job Title" field of a "Job". When you create a Job Posting, you select a Job that it references.

When I display a Job Posting, I want to display fields from the referenced Job. This would seem to be a pretty basic requirement. But how do I do this?

I tried creating a View with a Relationship based on the Entity Reference and a Contextual Filter based on Nid, but it never works.

What approaches have you used that work for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

On the view:
FILTER CRITERIA
Content: Type (= Job Posting)

RELATIONSHIPS
Entity Reference: Job Title
Content entity referenced from field_job_title

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6, I've used the reference views module to create field formatters for referenced nodes that go beyond the default title, node, etc.

In D7, you can use Entity Reference Views Formatter to do the same thing. Here's some more info: https://drupal.org/node/700950#comment-7298028RV

Comment: Thanks Doug. The settings I posted as an answer work though, for my requirements. I defined a view, and I show it as a block on the referencing content type. The view displays the fields from the referenced content type. It works.

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier way to make it using DS module.
In the manage display section of the Job posting type just check display as teaser.
And in the Job type just make the the display you want as a teaser.
In this case you can reuse this display in other places.

Love DS module.